# ES6 export from Syntax on submodule

Tags: babeljs, es6-module-loader

I have the following structure

```
 components/
   index.js
   Messages/
    index.js
    error.jsx
    info.jsx
    success.jsx
```

Messages/index.js export the three messages as :

```
export {Info} from './info'
export {Error} from './error'
export {Success} from './success'
```

And components/index.js does the following:

```
 import * as Message from './Message'
 export {Message}
```

Is there a way for me to do it without the import?

I am using webpack and  Babel with es2015 presets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Mozilla's ES2015 documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export you can just do

```
export * from './Messages';
```

Comment: Yeah that kinda worked, the only caveat is that i need to wrap the Message on Message/index.js So i can Use Message.Info and not just Info